# FX Swap PnL and NPV

Tags: interest-rates, fx, swaps, pnl

Suppose I have an existing FX Swap, suppose the spot leg is already settled, so only forward leg is left.

Question: What will be the P&L for this instrument - only forward leg NPV or spot leg is also marked-to-market to current spot rate?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the derivatives world cashflows that have been paid in the past drop out of the PV calculation. Since your spot leg is already settled there is nothing left of it you could mark-to-market.

Comment: I remember a bank that kept track of (foreign currency) cash flows throughout the lifetime of the derivative. IIRC, this was only for risk analysis, though - not for PnL

Answer (score 3):

While the near leg is settled, in order to get the full PnL of the trade, you will value the remaining leg of the swap, as well as asset from the settled leg.  However, there is a short cut as the settled short leg is valued at spot and the remaining long leg is valued at spot + forward points.  Since the settled short leg and the remaining long leg are opposite direction on spot, you only need to value the change in the forward points to your long leg date and discount at the discount rate in your functional currency.  (ie. spot is negated).

To illustrate:

In an fx swap, you will buy (or sell) a foreign currency at a near date and simultaneously sell (or buy) that foreign currency at a further date.

To make the fx swap simple (and create the scenario of the OP), let's just say the near date is spot and the far date is 1 month from now.  And the foreign currency is EUR and the base currency is USD.  And the direction is the trader is buying EUR spot and selling EUR 1 month out.  Let's assume spot EUR = 1 USD and the forward was traded at +0.10 USD forward points.

Upon settlement of the trade, the trader is now Long 1 EUR at 1 USD and Short 1 EUR 1M forward at 1.1 USD.

Say 1 week passes and the EUR has now moved to 1.1 USD and the 3 week forward is trading at spot + 0.11.

The trader is now long 1 EUR valued at 1.1 USD and short a 3 week EUR forward at 1.1 when the market is 1.21 (1.1 + 0.11 USD forward points).  The full PnL would be an appreciation of long EUR and the loss on the now 3 week forward.  One could value each of these legs by discounting these rates (obviously spot EUR would not be discounted).

Alternatively, since the long EUR and the short EUR forward are both exposed to spot in opposite directions, the remaining leg of the swap could be valued at the discounted value of just the change in the forward points.

**Important:**  this can only be done if it is an even fx swap (the notional of the near leg and the far leg are the same).  In real life, the fw swap is often an uneven swap and the individual legs will need to be valued according to the notional of each leg.  The spot exposures will not net out since the notionals are different on the near and far legs of the swap.